# New content page "missing assembly" error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to create a multiple page application, therefore i created a new content page. I want to switch between the pages. But these errors occur every time:

The errors:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Pages.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

How can I fix this? Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Hi,@alonewolf. Is your current project xamarin or wpf?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tagged it, I work with wpf. I want to create a new page, but when i press on add and on content page (page.xaml) these errors occur. How can I create an additional page beside my main window ?